Bulk convert bookmarks titles to lowercase
Is it possible to loop through all bookmarks in Firefox, change the "Name" to lowercase, trim the length to a certain limit and save it back? I tried creating an extension and it seems to be too much work. Does everything have to be an extension? Is there a console or something where I could quickly enter some code and run it to make these changes?
Is there an extension that already helps bulk renaming of bookmarks? The closest I found is this question and the method seems to be deprecated.
Before:

After:


It would be a lot easier to backup your bookamrks and process the json file from your favorite shell.

It is possible to use an extension to visit all bookmarks in Firefox, change the title to lowercase, trim the length to a certain limit, and save them back. However, it would require tree-walking to visit every bookmark. It's not a very efficient solution to accomplish a one-time task. The only practical reason to implement such a solution as an extension is to enforce those conditions automatically on new bookmarks as soon as they're made.
There is an extension (trying not to advertise in an answer) that allows running ad hoc code in a background context with access to many of the background APIs, like browser.bookmarks. However, that's still not the easiest solution as a one-time task.
I believe the easiest solution is a variation of @paa's suggestion.

Export Bookmarks to HTML
Open the file you just exported
Run the code below in the devtools console
Save the updated page (probably best as a different HTML file)
Delete all your bookmarks; Import Bookmarks from HTML

Array.from( document.getElementsByTagName( 'A' ) ).forEach( function ( a ) {
    a.textContent = a.textContent.slice( 0, 16 ).toLowerCase();
} )

Pick a different length than 16, if that's what you want. If you find step 5 a bit too scary at first, you can test it in a separate profile.
The bookmarks export is essentially a list of anchor tags. The code above selects all the A tags and loops through them to change the anchor text.

Clever! I know you didn't want to advertise the extension to which you alluded, but do you mind posting a link here in the comments?

Scratchpad
It's not fully-featured, but I like it.

I appreciate the link.
